# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^{672}-2\cos\left(x^{1007}\right)-\sin(x^{672})+2}{x^{2014}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there any way to find a limit besides using L'Hopital's rule?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^{672}-2\cos\left(x^{1007}\right)-\sin(x^{672})+2}{x^{2014}}$$

I'm asking because I tried to apply the rule 1 time and the expression becomes only worse. That's why I think that, may be, there is a trick.

Comment: It can be useful that 1007 is half 2014 and 672 is almost one third of 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Taylor series $\sin(y)=y+O(y^3)$ and $\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+O(y^3)$ we see easily that the desired limit is $1$.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Taylor expansion is a way. Start with pieces $$\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{24}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ $$\sin(y)=y-\frac{y^3}{6}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ So, replacing $y$ by what is required $$\cos(x^{1007})=1-\frac{x^{2014}}{2}+\frac{x^{4028}}{24}+\cdots$$ $$\sin(x^{672})=x^{672}-\frac{x^{2016}}{6}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $~\dfrac{1-\cos2t}2=\sin^2t,~$ and $~\sin u\sim u~$ as $~u\to0$.